# How to sum up the number of times a name is mentioned?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to make a Google sheets document right now - It's basically a roster for work. How can I create a cell in which I can display the amounts of shifts one person has worked?

In other words: What is the function to count the number of times a specific name is mentioned in the sheet?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: There are many approaches, I am partial to the QUERY() function but many are intimidated by it. COUNTIF() is also a good option.

Comment: If you are a beginner, countifs will be easier to pick up. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

let's say names are in A column try:

```
=QUERY(A:A; "select A,count(A) where A is not null group by A label count(A)''")
```